# I can't open a Python file from the Box desktop app

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a .py file from the Box desktop app, but when I open it with Visual Studio Code, I get this error: "The file is not displayed in the text editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding." What should I do?

I tried clicking "Open Anyway" but it didn´t work.

Comment: Try opening the file with a different text editor, like Notepad or TextEdit, to see if it displays correctly. If that doesn’t work, you may need to check the file content for any binary data or encoding issues.

Comment: I opened it with Notepad and it´s blank

Answer (score -1):

Triy opening it with editor.exe, the basic text editor. If the text you see there doesn't resemble python code, then the file is probably encrypted.